# PHP SoapFault not passing attributes in detail subelements

Tags: php, soap, soapfault

Webservice I'm calling returns SoapFault with xml embedded in `<detail>` element - this is how it looks in SoapUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
        <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
        <faultstring>some error msg</faultstring>
        <detail>
            <e:exchange-error xmlns:e="http://mycompany.com/faults">
                <e:message-data id="00001" type="005"/>
                <e:result-data date="2017-02-13 15:44:33" code="1401" ref="2457798154426512"/>
            </e:exchange-error>
        </detail>
    </soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`
```

It seems like PHP implementation does not pass the attributes of xml nodes, it just returns the values (which in this case, are empty):

```
try {
    $resp = $this->_soap->__soapCall("myMethod", ['param-data' => $req->get()]);
    var_dump($response);
} catch (\SoapFault $e) {
    if (empty($e->detail->{'exchange-error'}->{'result-data'})) {
        echo "it's empty :(\n";
        var_dump($e->detail->{'exchange-error'});
    }
}

$ php -f foobar.php
it's empty :(
object(stdClass)#7 (4) {
  ["message-data"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["result-data"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Is there a way to get `exchange-error` object with attribute values? Or maybe just get XML/string from `detail` and parse it? Fault message is defined in WSDL, so I guess its structure should be known on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace attributes are not returned in the php response. They are only used to define wich type of response object it is.

If you want to ease your day, use a WSDL to php generator such as the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project. It will ease you constructing the request, it will ease you receiving the response, finally it will ease you the handling of any error.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over what server omits in response - I just  need to identify the value of one of result-data attributes to implement special case of fault handling.